# INSERT after EXECUTE IMMEDIATE in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, toad, execute-immediate

I am trying to run execute immediate statement to create a table and after that I want to insert data to it but it shows me an error that my table doesn't exist:

```
DECLARE
    liczba NUMBER :=5;
BEGIN
    IF liczba > 1 THEN
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE TABLE person (name VARCHAR2(10))';
      INSERT INTO person VALUES ('John');
    END IF;
END;
```

The error is as follows:

> ORA-06550: line 9, column 17:   PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does
>   not exist   ORA-06550: line 9, column 5:   PL/SQL: SQL Statement
>   ignored

Is it possible to insert data without adding next execute immediate statement?
Why doesn't it see the table?

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33628951/266304) too, which has more explanation but is about a GTT so some doesn't directly apply. You still shouldn't generally be creating tables at rumtime though.

Comment: "Why doesn't it see the table?"   Because the table doesn't exist *at compile time*.  And if it did exist the EXECUTE IMMEDIATE would fail at run time. Basically your code mixes things we do only once (create a table) with things we do any number of times (insert a record). That's wrong.