# Table created in a procedure is dropped, Getting compilation error for procedure

Tags: oracle, procedure

The first step of created procedure is to check if table XYZ exist. If it does then go ahead with further calculation on the table XYZ but if it does not exist create the table and then go ahead with the calculation(inserting new records in the table).

So for testing purpose I dropped the table. The moment I dropped the table I am getting compilation error from the procedure saying that table does not exist.

How should I solve this issue.I can not change the logic.

Comment: Please post ( the relevant part of ) your code.

Comment: Post your code. Also you should use `execute immediate` in every reference to the `table` that may or may not exit. Otherwise you will get compilation errors.

Comment: Hi Plirkee, yes I tried using execute immediate by taking the query in a string. But the query is very large So I am getting error as string literal tooo long.

Comment: [Please see this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33628951/266304).

Comment: If your query string is too long (more than 32k??) then you'll have to build it up as a CLOB, in chunks shorter than that. That isn't what you asked about though...

Comment: I'll bet the code is based on the table itself where you are "doing calculation" on the table.  This code has a direct reference to the table, also called a dependency.  When you dropped the table, you broke the dependency, making your procedure invalid.  It will not compile until the table is in place.  Or, as mentioned above, you wrap the dependencies in EXECUTE IMMEDIATE blocks, which removes the direct dependency.

Answer (score 2):

Code which needs to check whether a table exists indicates bad software architecture. There should be no need to create tables on the fly. It's an anti-pattern (at least in Oracle). However, we see variations on this problem often enough, so it's obvious that this anti-pattern is thriving in the wild.

If you really need to implement such a solution (for whatever reason) the correct approach is to separate table building code from the table using code. Have separate packages for them.

```
begin
    pkg_ddl.build_table_xyz;
    pkg_calc.run_xyz_job;
end;
```

If table XYZ doesn't exist `pkg_calc.run_xyz_job()` is invalid. However it's invalidity won't prevent `pkg_ddl.build_table_xyz()` from executing. Then, when the outer program calls `pkg_calc.run_xyz_job()` it will compile the procedure.